# Making VLookup more able to accommodate structural changes in lookup table

Tags: vba, excel

With regard to the built-in Excel function: VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup).

This function is described at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/181213

As we know this function starts to give the wrong results if you insert a column in the middle of the lookup table. This is because the col_index_num parameter does not change to accommodate the new offset between the columns you are interested in.

The problem becomes worse when using a vlookup function from within VBA where the table_array range also lacks the ability to respond to movements in the lookup table.

The question: Is there an alternate function that can respond to structural changes in the lookup table without giving unexpected results (exact matches are required).

I am going to answer my own question in the event that my solution may be useful 
to others.

Comment: I rather use the `Application.Match`, and then you can just use `.Offset(0, NumofCols)` to how many columns you may have every time you run your code. Can you share a worksheet with sample data as example how you would like it being used ?

Comment: I sometimes just use `CELL("col",whichever_column_I_am_looking_for)` to work out where the column is - e.g. `=VLOOKUP(A1,D1:I11,CELL("col",H1)-3,FALSE)` (the `-3` there is because the table starts after the 3rd column of the worksheet, i.e. starts in column D)

Comment: Good point YowE3K. Perhaps then my code only has value when using vlookup from within VBA where it is not able to detect structural changes in the lookup table (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: I'd use a combination of `INDEX` and `MATCH`.  If your data table is in the range `A1:H22` with headers in row 1 and column A you could use `=INDEX($A$1:$H$22,MATCH("column A header",$A:$A,0),MATCH("row 1 header",$1:$1,0))`.  Has the added bonus of being non-volatile.

Comment: Thanks Darren. I have used INDEX and MATCH although it seems to consume too much CPU for a spreadsheet of any size when compared to VLookup. I have not yet tried my solution on a spreadsheet of any size yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a VBA function (VLOOKUP2) to address this issue but it does require the lookup table to have Headings. The function is used as follows:

Suppose you have a 3-column lookup table in a sheet called "People" with headings: Name,Gender,Age

You can find Sally's age by usung the following formula that uses the new VLOOKUP2 function:

```
=VLOOKUP2("People","Name","Age","Sally")
```

And you can catch failed matches in the normal way as follows:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP2("People","Name","Age","Sally")),"Name not Found",VLOOKUP2("Prople","Name","Age","Sally"))
```

Here is the VBA Code:

```
 Public Function VLOOKUP2(Sheet, LeftHeading, RightHeading, SearchTerm) As Variant
 'This function will search a lookup table in the sheet specified by the 1st parameter 'Sheet'
 'The Columns in the sheet must have a row of column headings at the top (1:1)
 'The function will look for the 'SeachTerm' in the Column given by 'LeftHeading'
 'Once found the function will return the value found in the column given by 'RightHeading'
 'The function must be public so that the function can be called directly from a spreadsheet cell
 Application.Volatile (True) 'Needed so that spreadsheet auto-calculation will trigger function execution
 Set RangeLeft = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(LeftHeading, LookIn:=xlValues)
 Set RangeRight = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(RightHeading, LookIn:=xlValues)
 'We must use SET because a range is an object (not using set would recover the .value of the range)
 If RangeLeft Is Nothing Then
  VLOOKUP2 = "Error: Can't find heading '" + LeftHeading + "'"
 ElseIf RangeRight Is Nothing Then
  VLOOKUP2 = "Error: Can't find heading '" + RightHeading + "'"
 Else
  RangeRefLeft = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(LeftHeading, LookIn:=xlValues).Address
  RangeRefRight = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(RightHeading, LookIn:=xlValues).Address
  ColLeft = Split(RangeRefLeft, "$")(1) 'Converts $G$1 into G (for example)
  ColRight = Split(RangeRefRight, "$")(1) 'Converts $E$1 into E (for example)
  Cols = Asc(ColRight) - Asc(ColLeft) + 1 'Works out how many columns are between the two headings
  If Len(ColRight) > 1 Then
   VLOOKUP2 = "Error: Lookup tables beyond Column Z are not supported"
  ElseIf Cols < 2 Then
   VLOOKUP2 = "Error: Left heading ('" + LeftHeading + "' at column " + ColLeft + ") & right heading ('" + RightHeading + "' at column " + ColRight + ") are out of order"
  Else
   VlookupRange = ColLeft + ":" + ColRight 'Gives us G:E (for example)
   'Finally we use the built-in Vlookup spreadsheet function:
   VLOOKUP2 = Application.Vlookup(SearchTerm, ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(VlookupRange), Cols, False)
   'We use 'False' so that an exact match is required (Failed matches give an #NA error)
   'This function (VLOOKUP2) must return a variant so that #NA can be passed back as an error
  End If
 End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

For catching failed matches :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP2("People","Name","Age","Sally"),"Name not Found")
```

Is shorter than your example - if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach this time. Still using the idea of searching under **named** column headings to help VBA survive from columns being unexpectedly moved around in the lookup table. This time though using FIND and returning an array of exactly matched results. I could not get FINDNEXT to work and instead I use FIND using the After:= parameter but careful to look out for when it wraps.
I find the array of matches returned to be useful when the function is called by other VBA routines although also handy when used in a spreadsheet cell to return the first match (example below). Although a bit clunky, the use of column headings seem to provide an extra level of "self-documentation" to the code as a whole.

```
Public Function FINDALL(Sheet, SearchHeading, SearchTerm, RetValHeading) As Variant()
 'This function searches under the given SearchHeading within the given sheet for matches against the SearchTerm
 'For each matching row it obtains the contents of the cell under the column given by the RetValHeading.
 'The values obtained are returned as an array. If the calling routine chooses to interpret the array as a single value then
 'it obtains the first match. If there are no matches then a "" string is returned (no error).
 'The Columns in the sheet must have a row of column headings at the top (1:1)
 'The function must be public so that the function can be called directly from a spreadsheet cell
 Dim RetValArray() As Variant ' We will grow the size of this array later using ReDim
 Application.Volatile (True) 'Needed so that spreadsheet auto-calculation will trigger function execution
 Set SearchRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(SearchHeading, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 Set RetValRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(RetValHeading, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
 'We must use SET because a range is an object (not using set would recover the .value of the range)
 If SearchRange Is Nothing Then
  ReDim RetValArray(0): RetValArray(0) = "Error: Can't find heading '" + SearchHeading + "'"
 ElseIf RetValRange Is Nothing Then
  ReDim RetValArray(0): RetValArray(0) = "Error: Can't find heading '" + RetValHeading + "'"
 Else
  SearchHeadingRangeRef = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(SearchHeading, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
  SearchCol = Split(SearchHeadingRangeRef, "$")(1) 'Converts $G$1 into G (for example)
  SearchRangeRef = SearchCol + ":" + SearchCol 'Now: G:G
  Set SearchRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(SearchRangeRef)
  RetValHeadingRangeRef = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range("1:1").Find(RetValHeading, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Address
  RetValCol = Split(RetValHeadingRangeRef, "$")(1) 'Converts $E$1 into E (for example)  Set SearchRange = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(SearchRangeRef)
  On Error GoTo errorHandler
  Matches = 0: SearchWrapped = False
  Set CellFound = SearchRange.Find(SearchTerm, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  If CellFound Is Nothing Then
   ReDim RetValArray(0): RetValArray(0) = ""
  Else
   CellFoundRef = CellFound.Address
   FirstCellFoundRef = CellFoundRef
   Do While Not SearchWrapped
    Matches = Matches + 1
    CellFoundRow = Split(CellFoundRef, "$")(2) 'Converts $G$5 into 5 (for example)
    RetValRef = RetValCol + CellFoundRow
    RetVal = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet).Range(RetValRef).Value
    If IsEmpty(RetVal) Then RetVal = ""
    ReDim Preserve RetValArray(Matches - 1)
    RetValArray(Matches - 1) = RetVal
    Set CellFound = SearchRange.Find(SearchTerm, After:=CellFound, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    CellFoundRef = CellFound.Address
    If CellFoundRef = FirstCellFoundRef Then SearchWrapped = True
   Loop
  End If
 End If
 FINDALL = RetValArray
Exit Function
errorHandler:
 ReDim RetValArray(0)
 RetValArray(0) = Err.Number + ": " + Err.Description
 FINDALL = RetValArray
End Function
```

Here's an example lookup table with the function being used at Cell G2:
[image]
In VBA use the (0) to get the first match eg:
FINDALL("MySheet", "Heading1", SearchTerm, "Heading2")(0)